# How can I get a layer with the same size of the original input using Conv2DTranspose in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This is summary of my model.
[image]

My model is basically similar to a convolution network.

I want my model to work regardless of the width of the input. So the width size appears as `None`.

and I attached decoders to my model using `Conv2DTranspose`.

However, there is a problem.

I expected the result from `Conv2DTranspose` to be the same size as the input, but it is not the same.

I set `stride` to `2` to reduce the number of parameters, and mode of `padding` is `same`, but I found a problem when the size is odd.

The following functions were used for convolution operations in `ConvCapsuleLayer (custom layer)`.

```
conv = K.conv2d(input_tensor_reshaped, self.W, (self.strides, self.strides),
                    padding=self.padding, data_format='channels_last')
```

and I used `Conv2DTranspose` for decoder as follows.

```
recon_1 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, (5,5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='decoder_1', activation='relu')(mask_layer)                
recon_2 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(8, (5,5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='decoder_2', activation='relu')(recon_1)                
recon_3 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (1,1), strides=(1, 1), padding='same',  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='decoder_3', activation='linear')(recon_2)
```

Then I get the following error message.

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [1,200,824,1] vs. [1,200,823,1]

How can I resolve this difference when the size is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a succession of downsampling by a factor of 2 (because of the stride) followed by deconvolutions (Conv2DTranspose) multiplying the size by 2 (again du to the stride=2), you can only use even dimensions.

If you absolutely must have inputs with an odd dimension, you will either have to use padding or throw away one line. You also have to be careful if you use successive downsampling operations (either with strides or with MaxPooling). Before each operation reducing the dimension, you must have a dimension that is a multiple of the downsampling factor.

Comment: I found that I can use `output_padding` to set the output shape. Could you tell me anything about it or where can I get information about it?

Comment: In https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose you can have a look at the end of the documentation, there is a formula explaining how the `output_shape` is influenced by the stride, the kernel size, the padding and the output padding. You should also have a look at the two papers linked as references below.